# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 7 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I did not know about this function. How much of reputation is needed to access http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval ?

Comment: @pabouk Only saw your comment just now. Site self-evaluation is just like the other [review queues](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), so I suspect you'll need at least 350 reputation for that (more on non-beta sites). Site evaluation is done once every 3 months, so the next round will be in January.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Washing on delicate or permanent press...is this more sustainable and also gets your clothes clean?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/washing-on-delicate-or-permanent-press-is-this-more-sustainable-and-also-gets)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Water heating / electricity production by using earth's warmth?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1172/water-heating-electricity-production-by-using-earths-warmth)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Getting rid of immature windfallen apples](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/getting-rid-of-immature-windfallen-apples)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How can I build a spinning wheel?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/how-can-i-build-a-spinning-wheel)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is bamboo fabric safe? What about its manufacture?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/is-bamboo-fabric-safe-what-about-its-manufacture)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Where can I find a detailed technical description of a system to use Biogas as a Vehicle fuel?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/where-can-i-find-a-detailed-technical-description-of-a-system-to-use-biogas-as-a)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Cost-effective alternative to rechargeable batteries?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/cost-effective-alternative-to-rechargeable-batteries)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 3):

I found generally, searching for three keywords (not necessarily tags) from each question, they all appeared on the first page of results. Not all have more than one answer - we could do with some additional answers on questions where there's one answer, and it hasn't been accepted.

We do have some good content here, and we have rapidly-increasing numbers of people finding us via search engines.

So the content we're all adding, is getting a decent-sized, and growing, audience.

Comment: I agree. Content is good, but more questions and answers would be nice. We also could do with more people taking part in the site's self-evaluation. Only the 3 moderators participated this time.